# Lua string gsub, not to use special %?

Tags: lua

All I want is just plain string replace, but it seems that in Lua, I have to deal with regular expression. I have managed to write the following code, but even the '%' in non-literal string variable seems to be treated as a special character and causes an error where it is pointed by `<--here` below.

How can I print `==hello%20world==` by the following code?

```
local path = "hello world"
path = path:gsub("( )", "%%20")

local test = "==$path=="
test = test:gsub("$path", path) <-- here

print(test)
```

Comment: Nitpick: Lua patterns are not regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `string.gsub` expects a pattern, but lua patterns are pretty simple, especially if you follow this rule: every special (non-alphanumeric) character can be literal if you preceed it by a `%`. Since you are using the percent sign also in the replacement string, things get a bit complicated. The solution for your problem is:

```
local path = string.gsub("hello world", "%s", "%%%%20") -- note the quadruple %
local test = string.gsub("==$path==", "(%$path)", path)
print(test)
```

I used the `%s` character class to match whitespace in the first gsub. For the second `gsub` I used `%` to escape the dollar sign and I put a capture around the match, which is good practice in my opinion because then you have fine control over what `%1`, `%2` etc. yield. But that is optional and only really required if you have more complex patterns.

To me it seems like you are doing this in an over-complicated way. What are you actually trying to achieve? In this case, I would solve this with `string.format`:

```
local test = string.format("==%s==", string.gsub("hello world", "%s", "%%20"))
```

You still need the double `%`, but it looks simpler to me.

But I feel that replacing spaces is weird, so maybe a string is not the right data structure here? You call that variable a path, so let's say the individual parts of that path are stored in a table. Then everything becomes:

```
local elements = {    
    "hello", "world"    
}    
local test = string.format("==%s==", table.concat(elements, "%20"))    
print(test)
```

This is pretty straight-forward, I think (no extra escaping needed, no string handling, which is a benefit, IMHO).

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to modify existing Lua script (actually, this is my first time even trying to use this language), so the `test = test:gsub("$path", path)` is the existing code that I cannot edit (well, at least, not without modifying the whole structure of the script), so I guess four `%`s is the way. Seems kind of stupid that I have to do that just to output one `%`.

Comment: I see. Then you might be better off with ESkris answer.

Answer (score 2):

Plain string replace function is absent in the Lua standard library, but you can implement it yourself:

```
-- Plain replacement (all characters are non-magic)
function string:replace(substring, replacement, n)
    return (self:gsub(substring:gsub("%p", "%%%0"), replacement:gsub("%%", "%%%%"), n))
end

local path = "hello world"
path = path:replace(" ", "%20")

local test = "==$path=="
test = test:replace("$path", path)

print(test)  -->  ==hello%20world==
```